# How to set the bars style in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

[image]

The 'One' is the default style in JFreeChart.

I want 'Two' style(bar).

Please What can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but perhaps with

```
chart.getPlot().setDrawingSupplier(supplier);
```

with a subclass of DrawingSupplier redefining the `getNextFillPaint()`; or use

```
 new DefaultDrawingSupplier(java.awt.Paint[] paintSequence, java.awt.Paint[] fillPaintSequence, java.awt.Paint[] outlinePaintSequence, java.awt.Stroke[] strokeSequence, java.awt.Stroke[] outlineStrokeSequence, java.awt.Shape[] shapeSequence)
```